# How do I implement a simple high score system in a quiz application in C# Console?

Tags: c#, console

I am trying to create a simple multiple choice quiz game that tallies a person's score and shows it to them at the end.

The problem is that my professor gave us an optional feature to add, which I have no idea on how to code. He wants the program to display the top 5 highest scores at the end of the game, and after searching so much I just couldn't figure it out due to my lack of experience with programming.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace TeamYeahGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Beginning:
            string username;
            int YourScore = 0;
            Console.SetWindowSize(75, 50);

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;//yellow's pretty good aesthetically and functionally
            Console.WriteLine("           ___________________________________________________            ");
            Console.WriteLine("          |                                                   |           ");
            Console.WriteLine("          |      Salutations! Brave hero of the class!        |           ");// "/" cannot be used for some reason in writelines
            Console.WriteLine("          |           Welcome to the legendary quiz           |           ");
            Console.WriteLine("          |              of IntrDev class TCOB2!              |           ");
            Console.WriteLine("          |                                                   |           ");
            Console.WriteLine("          |___________________________________________________|           ");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("First, you must enter your name."); 
            username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Good day, " + username + ", the following quiz will test your knowledge of"); // leave spaces for sentences between concatenated data
            Console.WriteLine("close strangers, goodluck.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();  //Clears the current screen, needs action such as "readline" so it won't supercede writelines


            Console.WriteLine("Quiz Time!");

            Console.WriteLine("Question 1: What is Frederick Bunao's favorite hobby?");
            Console.WriteLine("a) Writing");
            Console.WriteLine("b) Reading");
            Console.WriteLine("c) Gaming");
            Console.WriteLine("d) Sports");
            Console.WriteLine();
            string answer1 = "C";
            string usersAnswer1;

            Console.Write("Answer: ");
            usersAnswer1 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (usersAnswer1 == answer1)
                YourScore++;
            if (usersAnswer1 == answer1)
                Console.Beep(2500, 200);
            else Console.Beep(500, 800);

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("What is Frederick Bunao's second favorite hobby?");
            Console.WriteLine("a) Writing");
            Console.WriteLine("b) Reading");
            Console.WriteLine("c) Gaming");
            Console.WriteLine("d) Sports");
            string answer2 = "A";
            string usersAnswer2;

            Console.Write("Answer: ");
            usersAnswer2 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (usersAnswer2 == answer2)
                YourScore++;
            if (usersAnswer2 == answer2)
                Console.Beep(2500, 200);
            else Console.Beep(500, 800);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Which weapon would Frederick Bunao choose?");
            Console.WriteLine("a) Sword");
            Console.WriteLine("b) Dagger");
            Console.WriteLine("c) Staff");
            Console.WriteLine("d) Rocket Launcher");

            string answer3 = "C";
            string usersAnswer3;

            Console.Write("Answer: ");
            usersAnswer3 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (usersAnswer3 == answer3)
                YourScore++;
            if (usersAnswer3 == answer3)
                Console.Beep(2500, 200);
            else Console.Beep(500, 800);

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Who is Frederick Bunao's favorite writer?");
            Console.WriteLine("a) Stephen King");
            Console.WriteLine("b) Stephenie Meyer");
            Console.WriteLine("c) Mark Twain");
            Console.WriteLine("d) Edgar Allan Poe");
            string answer4 = "D";
            string usersAnswer4;

            Console.Write("Answer: ");
            usersAnswer4 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (usersAnswer4 == answer4)
                YourScore++;
            if (usersAnswer4 == answer4)
                Console.Beep(2500, 200);
            else Console.Beep(500, 800);

            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("What is Frederick Bunao's favorite game?");
            Console.WriteLine("a) FPS");
            Console.WriteLine("b) TPS");
            Console.WriteLine("c) RPG");
            Console.WriteLine("d) RTS");
            string answer5 = "C";
            string usersAnswer5;

            Console.Write("Answer: ");
            usersAnswer5 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (usersAnswer5 == answer5)
                YourScore++;
            if (usersAnswer5 == answer5)
                Console.Beep(2500, 200);
            else Console.Beep(500, 800);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("What is Lloyd Abella's favorite color?");
            Console.WriteLine("a) Blue");
            Console.WriteLine("b) Red");
            Console.WriteLine("c) Green");
            Console.WriteLine("d) Orange");
            string answer6 = "B";
            string usersAnswer6;

            Console.Write("Answer: ");
            usersAnswer6 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (usersAnswer6 == answer6)
                YourScore++;
            if (usersAnswer6 == answer6)
                Console.Beep(2500, 200);
            else Console.Beep(500, 800);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("What is Lloyd Abella's favorite number?");
            Console.WriteLine("a) 1");
            Console.WriteLine("b) 3");
            Console.WriteLine("c) 18");
            Console.WriteLine("d) 20");
            string answer7 = "C";
            string usersAnswer7;

            Console.Write("Answer: ");
            usersAnswer7 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (usersAnswer7 == answer7)
                YourScore++;
            if (usersAnswer7 == answer7)
                Console.Beep(2500, 200);
            else Console.Beep(500, 800);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("What is Lloyd Abella's favorite hobby?");
            Console.WriteLine("a) Basketball");
            Console.WriteLine("b) Table Tennis");
            Console.WriteLine("c) Volleyball");
            Console.WriteLine("d) Badminton");
            string answer8 = "A";
            string usersAnswer8;

            Console.Write("Answer: ");
            usersAnswer8 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (usersAnswer8 == answer8)
                YourScore++;
            if (usersAnswer8 == answer8)
                Console.Beep(2500, 200);
            else Console.Beep(500, 800);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Who is Lloyd Abella's favorite celebrity?");
            Console.WriteLine("a) Jake Cuenca");
            Console.WriteLine("b) Coco Martin");
            Console.WriteLine("c) John Lloyd");
            Console.WriteLine("d) Gabriel Gaerlan");
            string answer9 = "C";
            string usersAnswer9;

            Console.Write("Answer: ");
            usersAnswer9 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (usersAnswer9 == answer9)
                YourScore++;
            if (usersAnswer9 == answer9)
                Console.Beep(2500, 200);
            else Console.Beep(500, 800);
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("How old is Lloyd Abella?");
            Console.WriteLine("a) 16");
            Console.WriteLine("b) 17");
            Console.WriteLine("c) 15");
            Console.WriteLine("d) 12");
            string answer10 = "B";
            string usersAnswer10;

            Console.Write("Answer: ");
            usersAnswer10 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (usersAnswer10 == answer10)
                YourScore++;
            if (usersAnswer10 == answer10)
                Console.Beep(2500, 200);
            else Console.Beep(500, 800);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Your score is being calculated. Please type any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            if (YourScore == 10)
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations! You got a perfect score of 10!");
            else if (YourScore == 9 || YourScore == 8 || YourScore == 7)
                Console.Write("Great Job!! You got a " + YourScore + "!!");
            else if (YourScore == 6 || YourScore == 5)
                Console.Write("You got a " + YourScore + ", kinda good I guess");
            else if (YourScore < 5)
                Console.Write("Your score is...     " + YourScore + "    unfortunately, you failed the quiz");


            Console.WriteLine();
            string usersChoice;
            string answer = "Y";



            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)");
            usersChoice = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            if (usersChoice == answer) //use this type of if statement for Y/N stuff
            {
                goto Beginning;
            }

                Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Way too much code for asking the core question.

Comment: Just a friendly advice: Try to use a loop (see the "while" keyword) instead of a goto.

Answer (score 8):

Since this is homework, I'll give you a starting point.

Store all of the scores in a list.  If you sort the list (or better... use a list implementation that sorts for you...) you can get the top scores by looking at the first 5 entries of the sorted list.

See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx

Comment: I'm sorry for putting too much code, I'm fairly new to this site. I'm going to try to learn to use sorted list it's just a bit complicated, hopefully I can get it by tomorrow. Thanks!